# Why do YouTube videos take longer than the length of the video to load?

Tags: video, appletv, youtube

I've been using my AppleTV (3rd generation) to watch YouTube videos for some time, and have been encountering an increasingly frustrating issue. Videos have been taking longer to load than the length of the video itself when this problem occurs.

I watch a lot of segments/clipped shows whose video lengths are around 10 minutes. On a good day the Apple TV keeps a buffer of at least 30 seconds in length out from the position in the video. On a bad day, if I were to let the video load, it would take around 30 minutes to load the 10 minute video.

My network connection is otherwise stable for a myriad of wireless devices (Computers, iPhones, iPads, Game Consoles both plugged into the TV and portable), there is literally no Cat5 cable in my house except for the one linking the Cable Modem to the Time Capsule (purchased in 2009).

And this only seems to affect the YouTube app. Hulu and Netflix take around 3 to 5 seconds to load a video, but afterwards I never encounter any sort of quality reduction or pause for buffering. This YouTube app problem happens on a daily basis, but not consistently. Additionally, the same video does not always exhibit this problem, sometimes switching videos and switching back resolves it, other times I cannot resolve it at all, give up and do something else.

Why is this happening? How can I diagnose the source of this extreme slowness using the YouTube app on my AppleTV?

Comment: This is far from an answerable question without knowing your ISP, Router, and DNS settings.

Comment: It could be youtube that is the problem. I've seen it stop dead in it's tracks on a 150/65 Mbit/s FIOS connection. As Richard mentioned it could be anything without knowing all the details.

Comment: I figured by saying that it was a single device within a household (AppleTV) that my ISP, Router, and DNS settings, would be completely irrelevant.

Comment: Does YouTube load OK on the iPad?  My phone's YouTube performance is abysmal.  I think it's an Apple-vs-YouTube thing, although there are lots of posts out there that say tweaking your DNS settings can improve this.

Comment: YouTube loads perfectly fine on every device (including the Xbox and PS3 that are in the same entertainment center as the Apple TV), except the AppleTV. I'm using Comcast's provided DNS servers, but that's also true of every device in the house. I can try changing the DNS settings via the router to OpenDNS or Google Public DNS or something else.

Comment: And not two days later, suddenly other devices have very similar throughput problems as the AppleTV. Not nearly as slow, but the fact that it has to keep buffering is absolutely frustrating.

Comment: Brand new Apple TV, different house, different ISP (Optimum Online), geographically different location, and it's exhibiting all of the same issues. This is really frustrating as it's the only device to have so many problems with YouTube so consistently.